# Cleaning Geocode Data

Tags: r, regex, leaflet, stringr, geocode

I've got a df just like this:

```
df = data.frame(longitude = c('-235.969', 
                       '-23.596.244', 
                       '-2.359.186'))
```

It´s an example of one column of geocode I'm trying to convert to something like this

```
new_df = data.frame(longitude = c('-23.5969', '-23.596244', '-23.59186'))
```

The main purpose is to use the geocode in an leaflet application.

Comment: There are ways to do this with regex, but, I would first ask how did you get your original `df` in the first place? Maybe something in the creation of `df` could change

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub('(-?\\d{2})(.*)', '\\1.\\2', gsub('\\.', '', df$longitude)))` maybe, but agreed that this should probably get fixed upstream.

Comment: I received from a company case, but I put here the 3 different shapes the numbers appeared. I thought about looking in the documentation of the read.csv, but I couldn´t find anything. In the Excel, it opened just like this, but its reader interpreted properly. Maybe using some function from the excel's openning packages could manage this in a easier way?

Comment: @RafaelBicudo Excel might be the culprit. I would ty opening the csv file in a text editor in see it's logic and/or trying imporiting directly to R with `data.table::fread()`.

Comment: @snoram same error. Probably the error is at the orginal source from the company that sent me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If really necessary, I would do this in two steps:

```
library(magrittr)
gsub(".", "", df$longitude, fixed = TRUE) %>%
  sub("(\\d{2})", "\\1\\.", .)

[1] "-23.5969"   "-23.596244" "-23.59186"
```

First drop any `.` then replace the first two digits with the first two digits + `.`

PS. without pipes you could do:

```
sub("(\\d{2})", "\\1\\.", gsub(".", "", df$longitude, fixed = TRUE))
```

**EDIT: *Important caveat***:

As Matt points out this only works if your longitude **ALWAYS** consist of if your longitude degree is two digits (10-99).

Comment: Doesn't this only work if you can be sure that all your longitude values are between –99º and +99º? Otherwise your regex would replace -122.41º (e.g. San Francisco) with -12.241 (at the same latitude, a point in the Atlantic ~200km west of Lisbon).

Comment: Correct. But can you read anything more into the logic of the original post?

Comment: No, I can't work out what the second . might represent. My first thought was degrees.minutes.seconds, but the numbers are too large. As @SymbolixAU commented above, the solution here is going to come from understanding how the data ended up that way in the first place.

Comment: As I said above, I received this from a business case. It is a csv file, but the excel read it  better than the read.csv function (literally, it was like I put here with this pattern). Maybe, using an excel file reader function, could I get a better result?